# PHP closure scope problem

Tags: php, scope, closures

Apparently $pid is out of scope here. Shouldn't it be "closed" in with the function? I'm fairly sure that is how closures work in javascript for example.

According to some articles [php closures are broken](http://justafewlines.com/2009/10/whats-wrong-with-php-closures/), so I cannot access *this*?

So how can *$pid* be accessed from this closure function?

```
class MyClass {
  static function getHdvdsCol($pid) {
    $col = new PointColumn();
    $col->key = $pid;
    $col->parser = function($row) {
        print $pid; // Undefined variable: pid
    };
    return $col;
  }
}

$func = MyClass::getHdvdsCol(45);
call_user_func($func, $row);
```

**Edit** I have gotten around it with use: `$col->parser = function($row) use($pid)`. However I feel this is ugly.

Comment: It is not ugly, it is how closures work in php

Comment: that's just how it is in php so..

Comment: It's an ugly language, but I'm stuck with it. :(

Comment: It becomes less and less ugly every day. (:

Comment: From PHP 5.4 you can access `$this` within the closure.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to specify which variables should be closed in this way:

```
function($row) use ($pid) { ... }
```

Comment: If this closure is saved in a variable and then passed to another scope where $pid does not exist, will pid be wrapped in the closure somehow, or not accessible?

Comment: @Josh Nankin: actually `use($var,...)` is how closures are implemented in php. So if you pass the anonymous function to another variable scope - the `$pid` variable will contain the last defined value.

Comment: Does this "use" thingy feel just weird or is it just me? I just can't get over it after using closures in other languages. :/

Comment: @Matjaz Muhic: yep, it's weird for everyone not just you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bindTo method.

```
class MyClass {
  static function getHdvdsCol($pid) {
    $col = new PointColumn();
    $col->key = $pid;
    $parser = function($row) {
        print $this->key;
    };
    $col->parser = $parser->bindTo($parser, $parser);
    return $col;
  }
}

$func = MyClass::getHdvdsCol(45);
call_user_func($func, $row);
```

Answer (score -4):

I think PHP is very consistent in scoping of variables. The rule is, if a variable is defined outside a function, you must specify it explicitly. For lexical scope 'use' is used, for globals 'global' is used.

For example, you can't also use a global variable directly:

```
$n = 5;

function f()
{
    echo $n; // Undefined variable
}
```

You must use the global keyword:

```
$n = 5;

function f()
{
    global $n;
    echo $n;
}
```